# Using T-SQL parameters to filter the table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-injection

See this simple stored procedure:

```
getUsers(@name, @age, @city) etc...
```

- if I pass the age just filter for the age
- if I pass the name and city filter for both parameters

I know that there is a way to build my SQL statement and then `EXEC(mySQL)`

but I want do something Like:

```
SELECT * into #tmp From Users WHERE active = 1
if(@name)
   SELECT * into #tmp From #tmp WHERE name = @name
if(@age)
   SELECT * into #tmp From #tmp WHERE age = @age
if(@city)
   SELECT * into #tmp From #tmp WHERE city = @city
SELECT * From #tmp -- result
```

This way we can avoid SQL injection.

Comment: To clarify, what server-side processing language are you using with T-SQL (PHP, C#.Net, VB.Net, Java, etc.)?

Comment: Does this really have to be done in a stored procedure? @AR's answer is correct and would work but you could get a much more efficient query if it could be built within your application before being sent to the database, and this can be done without the risk of SQL injection. There are many questions on here on similar subjects so depending on your applciation there should be an answer to suit.

Comment: I am using C# to exec the current store procedure... But what I am going to do is using Parameters with Dynamic SQL as suggested in this article and build my query with C#. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx#paght000002_step3

Answer (score 4):

Seems to me using dynamic SQL here would make you more vulnerable to an injection attack. Try:

```
select *
-- into #tmp
from Users
where active = 1
    or (@age is not null and age = @age)
    or (@name is not null and name = @name)
    or (@city is not null and city = @city)
```

Not sure why you need a temporary table if you're just returning results of a query? Unless you have use for it elsewhere.

Comment: Should `WHERE Actve = 1` not be independant from the remaing clauses? This query will return results where active <> 1 if age = @age for example. This has already been accepted as an answer but it seems to me the where clause should be `WHERE Active = 1 AND (@age IS NULL OR Age = @age) AND (@Name IS NULL OR Name = @Name) AND (@City IS NULL OR City = @City).

Comment: I would guess you're right, but I was just basing my logic on what he had in his question. Of course it can be tweaked to suit the actual needs. :)

Comment: If I pass the name and city that doesn't filter both... Also, because all  joins are with OR's that bring me inactives records when any other filter is true and is inactive.

Comment: This is more close what I am looking for:
`select *
-- into #tmp
from Users
where active = 1
    AND (@age is null or age = @age)
    AND (@name is null or name = @name)
    AND (@city is null or city = @city)`

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use parameterized SQL using sp_ExecuteSQL in the stored procedure which protects you from SQL Injection

e.g.

```
DECLARE @SQL Nvarchar(max)
SET @SQL ='select *
           from Users 
           where active = 1'

IF @Name is not null 
    SET @SQL = @SQL + ' AND name = @Name'
IF @Age is not null
    SET @SQL = @SQL + ' AND age = @Age'

IF @City is not null
    SET @SQL = @SQL + ' AND city = @City'

exec sp_executeSQL @SQL, N'@Age int,
                         @Name varchar(255), @City varchar(255)',
                         @Age, 
                         @Name, 
                         @City
```

In this simple case its probably not worth it and I would use [technique described by AR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9593260/119477) but if your query is complicated enough it might be worth it.

For example lets assume that city was in another table and the record wasn't always there. With AR's technique you'd need to do this

```
select *
-- into #tmp
from Users
     LEFT JOIN user_city 
     ON user.user_Id = user_city.user_Id
         and @City is not null --We only want the join when @City is passed in
where active = 1
    or (@age is not null and age = @age)
    or (@name is not null and name = @name)
    or (@city is not null and city = @city)
```

Note the `LEFT JOIN`. With dynamic SQL you would simply dynamically add an `INNER JOIN` when you need it which would yield better performance in some cases.

Answer (score -1):

I believe what your looking for is dynamic SQL. The idea is to build a string which is your query, then use EXEC (or sp_executesql) to run your string as a SQL statement.

So to give you an idea, something like:

```
set @sql = 'select * into #tmp1 From #tmp2 '    
if @name = @someValidUserInput
begin
   set @sql = @sql + ' where name = @name'
   ...
end
exec(@sql)
```

Comment: That is what I current have and try to get away... this can cause vulnerability to the system (SQl injection) that is way I try to change.

Comment: Not if you validate your user input which what I meant by `if @name = @someValidUserInput`. The user provided string is only included in your query if the value is known to be valid.

Comment: if you look for name = Jaider's you would provide `@name='Jaider''''s'` otherwise that doesn't work... but the solution selected that was I looking for, just need to pass `@name='Jaider''s'`